# Poor loss convergence and accuracy with CNN model

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I've built a binary classifier using TF which classify's a 16x16 gray scale image into one of two classes with distribution 87-13. The issue that I'm having is that the model's [log loss converges to ~0.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS9q2.png), which is better than random however I cannot get it to improve beyond this.

The vision problem is in the realm of video encoding, [This image should provide some understanding to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uE7m.jpg), where images are are either to be or not to be split (0/1) based on their homogeneity. Note squares near edges are more likely sub-split to smaller ones.

When validating the model (1.1e7 examples, 87-13 distribution), I cannot achieve an [F1-score better than ~50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaYgl.png).

My training data consists of 2.2e8 examples which are oversampled/undersampled to achieve 50-50 distribution. I'm using a batch size of 1024 a substantial shuffle buffer (the data isn't ordered to begin with). Optimised using Adam, with default hyperparameters.

Things I've tried to improve the performance (test (outcome)):

- Larger networks, changing number of layers, activations, convolutional kernel sizes and strides etc (same convergence)
- Dropout between dense layers(Same performance as with large nets, worse performance with small nets)
- Other Adam hyperparameters (all lead to same convergence, eventually)
- Other optimisers (same as above)
- Training with very small dataset to test convergence (loss saturates to 0)
- Regularising input (no effect)
- Varying batch size (just influences the noise in the loss and convergence time)

I've been stuck trying to get the performance to improve, I think I've read every SO question that I could find. Any advice would be a great help.

```
def cnn_model(features, labels, mode):
#   downsample to 8x8 using 2x2 local averaging
    features_8x8 = tf.nn.avg_pool(
            value=tf.cast(features["x"], tf.float32),
            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
            strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
            padding="SAME",
            data_format='NHWC'
            )
    conv2d_0 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=features_8x8,
                                filters=6,
                                kernel_size=[3, 3],
                                strides=(1, 1),
                                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                name="conv2d_0")
    pool0 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
            inputs=conv2d_0,
            pool_size=(2, 2),
            strides=(2, 2),
            padding="SAME",
            data_format='channels_last'
            )
    conv2d_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool0,
                                filters=16,
                                kernel_size=[3, 3],
                                strides=(3, 3),
                                activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                name="conv2d_1")
    reshape1 = tf.reshape(conv2d_1, [-1, 16])
    dense0 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=reshape1,
                             units=10,
                             activation=tf.nn.relu,
                             name="dense0")
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense0,
                             units=1,
                             name="logits")

    # ########################################################

    predictions = {
            "classes": tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)),
            "probabilities": tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
            }

    # ########################################################

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          predictions=predictions)

    # ########################################################

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=tf.cast(labels['y'], tf.float32),
            logits=logits
            )

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

    # ########################################################

    # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mdoe)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001,
                                           beta1=0.9,
                                           beta2=0.999,
                                           epsilon=1e-08)
        train_op = optimiser.minimize(
                loss=loss,
                global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train_op)
    # Add evalutation metrics (for EVAL mode)
    eval_metric_ops = {
            "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
                    labels=labels["y"],
                    predictions=predictions["classes"]),
            }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have done a lot already. My next steps would be visualization of

- the dataset: can humans distinguish the classes?
- the weights: do they converge / change during training
- how do fine-tuned models like VGG work?

Possibly, you are asking for a very difficult vision problem. Can we see the images or get a sample of the data? Then, experienced people could try to come up with a basic model that is (hopefully) working...

Comment: I've added info regarding the vision problem in an edit (paragraph 2). 
How would you suggest I monitor the weights using TensorBoard? What exactly am I looking for? (could you provide a source?)

Comment: This is the correct answer (re the dataset: can humans distinguish the classes). While each training examples label is 0|1, not all classifications that the encoder makes have the same certainty, ie: some labels are better than others. Thus, it is likely that the model is having issues discerning the class of an encoded tile that was encoded without strong certainty.